# 3g модем huawei e303 настройка на linux

Tags: linux, модемы, 3g

Пытаюсь настроит модем huawei e303, перевел его в stick режим, появились два устройства ttyusb0 и ttyusb1 поставил minicom программу, и не могу с помощью ее отправить команды, тупо не на одну кнопку не реагирует

В какую сторону копать?

Comment: https://zieren.de/raspberry-pi/huawei-e303-3g-stick/